# Requests getting queued in IIS worker process at ExecuteRequestHandler

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, coldfusion, queue, worker-process

For some reason, the requests in one of our app pools started "hanging up" today.  The CPU usage is low, as is memory consumption, but requests in a worker are coming in and just getting queued; they are all stuck at state "ExecuteRequestHandler".

We can recycle the pool, and things work for like a minute, but stuff starts getting queued up again.  When you access a page, you never get any kind of error, the browser load icon just keeps spinning and nothing happens (indefinitely).

The app pool is set to "No Managed Code" and is in "Classic" mode.  We use things like the IIS rewrite tool, but we do not run anything ASP.NET; all of our sites are either static HTML or Coldfusion 9.

Just wondering if anyone else has experienced a similar issue before with requests getting queued like so in an IIS worker...

Answer (score 1):

This may be relevant: 
http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2011/11/5/maxworkerthreads.bug

You may have to increase the connector's maxworkerthreads size.